# Maven alternative (equivalent) of Gradle Application plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins, build, gradle

I'm building my project with Maven, but I haven't found the equivalent of Gradle's [Application Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) yet.

Is there some good Maven plugin for creating distribution .zip? Such us Gradle's Application Plugin? More to the point: Such as Gradle task "distZip" inside Application plugin -   Creates a full distribution ZIP archive including runtime libraries and OS specific scripts.

What do Maven users use to solve this use case?

Comment: No idea why you vote to close such question..

Comment: Who vote for closing?

Comment: Ok. I thought you were addressing to me.

Comment: No, definitely not. For close voters: he's not looking for a tool, he's already found it - it's maven. He's now asking how to perform a particular task in maven - and an example for this task is taken from gradle.

Comment: @Filip: perhaps a bit late but have you seen the appassembler plugin?  http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/

Comment: Yes, I've solved with that. Thanks.

Comment: The link seems to 404, @mpkorstanje

Comment: Can't edit my comment anymore https://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/

Comment: I solved it with the appassembler plugin:
mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin

Comment: maven-assembly is about packaging. gradle application is mostly about execution of a application through a build,naturally that implies also bundling.  gradle distribution would be somewhat a equivalent to maven-assembly

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: [maven-assembly](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-assemblies.html)

Comment: That doesn't do at all what gradle's application plugin is doing. It throws all the jars (with all the complications involved) together and makes the main jar executable. Gradle places all dependencies in a folder and creates startup script to execute them.

Comment: maven-assembly is about packaging. gradle application is mostly about execution of a application through a build. gradle distribution would be somewhat a equivalent to maven-assembly

Answer (score -2):

The maven assembly plugin is more powerful.
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: maven-assembly is about packaging. gradle application is mostly about execution of a application through a build. gradle distribution would be somewhat a equivalent to maven-assembly